# Cascading for overloaded + operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here's the current code:

```
const complex complex::operator+(const complex &right)
{
     complex result;
     result.realPart = realPart + right.realPart;
     result.imPart = imPart + right.imPart;
     return result;
}
```

How do i modify so that

a = b + c + d;

is allowed?

Comment: There is already a [`std::complex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/).

Answer (score 5):

Make it a const member function:

```
const complex complex::operator+(const complex &right) const ...
```